# Use parameters in subfields with graphene-django without relay for pagination purpose

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I'm using graphene with django and I'm struggling to do something that in my head should be very simple, but I don't find it documented anywhere in graphene docs or github nor did I see similar question here. The closest to it I found was:
https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-python/8-pagination/ but as you can see I'd have to declare the parameters in the parent resolver which I don't want to.

I have a query like this

```
  getUser(id: $userIdTarget) {
    id
    username
    trainings{
      id
      name
      sessions{
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to implement a pagination in the sessions subfield. So this is what I would like:

```
  getUser(id: $userIdTarget) {
    id
    username
    trainings{
      id
      name
      sessions(first:10){
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and in the resolver I'd implement something like this:

```
def resolve_sessions(root, info, first=None, skip=None):
        if skip:
            return gql_optimizer.query(Session.objects.all().order_by('-id')[skip:], info)
        elif first:
            return gql_optimizer.query(Session.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:first], info)
        else:
            return gql_optimizer.query(Session.objects.all().order_by('-id'), info)
```

(gql_optimizer is just an optimization wrapper library I use)

However this doesn't work as the field sessions correspond to a list of a model Session that is a fk to Training according to my django models, so this is automatically resolved by graphene because these types are DjangoObjectType , so I'm not really sure how can one customize these resolvers (or if it's even possible).

I'll leave the relevant models and types below:

**Session model**

```
class Session(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Session\'s name')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=240, choices=SESSION_CATEGORIES, default="practice",
                                help_text='Session type. Can be of \'assessment\''
                                          'or \'practice\'')
    total_steps = models.IntegerField(default=1, help_text='Amount of steps for this session')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=timezone.now, help_text='Time the session was created'
                                                                                      '(Optional - default=now)')
    completed_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Time the session was finished'
                                                                                         '(Optional - default=null)')
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="training_sessions", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    training = models.ForeignKey("Training", related_name="sessions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**UserType**

```
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = "__all__"


    @classmethod
    def get_queryset(cls, queryset, info, **kwargs):
        if info.variable_values.get('orgId') and info.variable_values.get('orgId') is not None:
            return queryset.order_by('username')
        return queryset
```

**SessionType**

```
class SessionType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Session
        fields = "__all__"
        convert_choices_to_enum = False

    @classmethod
    def get_queryset(cls, queryset, info, **kwargs):
        if info.variable_values.get('userId') and info.variable_values.get('userId') is not None:
            return queryset.filter(Q(user_id=info.variable_values.get('userId'))).order_by('-id')
        return queryset
```

**TrainingType**

```
class TrainingType(gql_optimizer.OptimizedDjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Training
        fields = "__all__"
        convert_choices_to_enum = False
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to extend your types to add more fields that aren't in the Django model -- perhaps that is the technique you are looking for to inject more data into the query?

```
class TrainingType(gql_optimizer.OptimizedDjangoObjectType):
    my_extra_field = graphene.Int() # for example

    class Meta:
        model = Training
        fields = "__all__"
        convert_choices_to_enum = False
```

You can also override the default resolvers that are created with `DjangoObjectType`.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer and upvoted cause at the time I read it all made sense and seemed to be the answer. Today I had a chance to try and unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. This does not work for the subfields that are automatically created from a foreign key relationship

Comment: You can also add objects as additional fields, and then further extend your custom resolve to populate those fields.